# Mounting HPFS partition read/write?

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, drivers

I'm not talking about NTFS partitions that show up as HPFS/NTFS. Is mounting actual HPFS partitions read/write possible?

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:sorry was misreading HFS with HPFS.**

HPFS could be be mounted but you need HPFS support in your kernel as it is pretty outdated you can try this driver for an old linux kernel:
[old linux driver found here](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~mikulas/vyplody/hpfs/index-e.cgi)

--

> Yes it is and I hope you found the answer already :)
>
> But I post here for the people who came directed by Doctor Google.
>
> Read AND write access of hfs+ in linux is only possible if journaling
>   is disabled usually done from within OS X terminal.
>
> ```
> diskutil disableJournal /Volumes/NameOfYourVolume
> ```
>
> then you can mount it with
>
> ```
> sudo mount -t hfsplus -o rw,remount -force /dev/sdX /myHPFS/mountpoint
> ```
>
> eventually you have to run for repairing the filesystem
>
> ```
> sudo fsck.hfsplus -f /dev/sdX
> ```
>
> If you still encounter problems, its likely to the wonderful invention
>   of Apple Core Storage.
>
> solved [in this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/961401/mounting-hfs-partition-on-arch-linux/1088110#1088110)